# Skaffold cannot pull image from Harbor

Tags: skaffold, jib, google-cloud-code, maven-jib

#### Expected behavior

Skaffold should pull the image from insecure Harbor registry running on HTTP. I have tried everything from these docs:
https://skaffold.dev/docs/environment/image-registries/#insecure-image-registries
but without success.

#### Actual behavior

Jib is pushing image to the insecure Harbor registry without a problem, but error is thrown when trying to pull the image and deploy microservice to Kubernetes:
`192.168.2.24:30002/trm/redis-spring:latest@sha256:0f8d21819d845bd55aa699afa8b21e141d41f10d9d9fb1a2c6dbb2d468d89e81 can't be pulled.`
Specified image can be pulled using docker:
`docker pull 192.168.2.24:30002/trm/redis-spring:latest@sha256:0f8d21819d845bd55aa699afa8b21e141d41f10d9d9fb1a2c6dbb2d468d89e81`

#### Information

- Skaffold version: v1.35.1
- Operating system: Windows 10 Home
- Installed via: skaffold.dev
- Contents of skaffold.yaml:

```yaml
apiVersion: skaffold/v2beta25
kind: Config
metadata:
  name: redis
build:
  insecureRegistries:
    - 192.168.2.24:30002/trm
    - 192.168.2.24:30002/trm/redis-spring
    - 192.168.2.24:30002/trm/redis-spring:latest@sha256:0f8d21819d845bd55aa699afa8b21e141d41f10d9d9fb1a2c6dbb2d468d89e81
  artifacts:
    - image: redis-spring
      jib:
        args:
          - -Pjib
          - -DsendCredentialsOverHttp=true
  tagPolicy:
    gitCommit: {}
deploy:
  kubectl:
    manifests:
      - redis-spring-boot.yaml
```

````
time="2022-02-02T11:12:40+01:00" level=debug msg="marking resource failed due to error code STATUSCHECK_IMAGE_PULL_ERR" subtask=-1 task=Deploy
 - mdm-dev:deployment/redis-spring-boot: container redis-spring is waiting to start: 192.168.2.24:30002/trm/redis-spring:latest@sha256:0f8d21819d845bd55aa699afa8b21e141d41f10d9d9fb1a2c6dbb2d468d89e81 can't be pulled
    - mdm-dev:pod/redis-spring-boot-68ccfdc688-tj7pp: container redis-spring is waiting to start: 192.168.2.24:30002/trm/redis-spring:latest@sha256:0f8d21819d845bd55aa699afa8b21e141d41f10d9d9fb1a2c6dbb2d468d89e81 can't be pulled
 - mdm-dev:deployment/redis-spring-boot failed. Error: container redis-spring is waiting to start: 192.168.2.24:30002/trm/redis-spring:latest@sha256:0f8d21819d845bd55aa699afa8b21e141d41f10d9d9fb1a2c6dbb2d468d89e81 can't be pulled.
time="2022-02-02T11:12:40+01:00" level=debug msg="setting skaffold deploy status to STATUSCHECK_IMAGE_PULL_ERR." subtask=-1 task=Deploy```
````

Comment: I believe the messages are from your k8s cluster and this is when your k8s cluster (not you or Skaffold locally) cannot pull an image (e.g., due to missing credentials). For example, https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/skaffold/issues/4851

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure a *registry pull secret* for your cluster, and then either annotate [your pod-specs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/) or your [service account](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/#add-imagepullsecrets-to-a-service-account) to use this registry pull secret.

Comment: Will your solution also work for my problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74817487/how-to-use-a-local-cluster-by-skaffold-while-using-kubeadm-for-the-kubernet

Comment: Very likely: `xxx can't be pulled` is a symptom of this problem.

Comment: I tried to install kind to resolve the issue. But still having problems configuring `skaffold` for using `kind` https://serverfault.com/questions/1118346/error-in-configuration-context-was-not-found-for-specified-context-kind-kind?noredirect=1#comment1460597_1118346