# How to use a local cluster by "Skaffold" while using "Kubeadm" for the "Kubernetes"?

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, redis, skaffold

I am trying to deploy my NodeJS application on a local Kubernetes cluster, using `skaffold` but I get the following result:

```
DEBU[0018] Pod "expiration-depl-7989dc5ff4-lkpvw" scheduled but not ready: checking container statuses  subtask=-1 task=DevLoop
DEBU[0018] marking resource failed due to error code STATUSCHECK_IMAGE_PULL_ERR  subtask=-1 task=Deploy
 - deployment/expiration-depl: container expiration is waiting to start: learnertester/expiration:8c6b05f89e0abe8e6a33da266355cf79713e6bd22d1abda0da5541f24d5d8d9e can't be pulled
    - pod/expiration-depl-7989dc5ff4-lkpvw: container expiration is waiting to start: learnertester/expiration:8c6b05f89e0abe8e6a33da266355cf79713e6bd22d1abda0da5541f24d5d8d9e can't be pulled
 - deployment/expiration-depl failed. Error: container expiration is waiting to start: learnertester/expiration:8c6b05f89e0abe8e6a33da266355cf79713e6bd22d1abda0da5541f24d5d8d9e can't be pulled.
DEBU[0018] marking resource status check cancelledSTATUSCHECK_USER_CANCELLED  subtask=-1 task=Deploy
DEBU[0018] marking resource status check cancelledSTATUSCHECK_USER_CANCELLED  subtask=-1 task=Deploy
DEBU[0018] marking resource status check cancelledSTATUSCHECK_USER_CANCELLED  subtask=-1 task=Deploy
DEBU[0018] marking resource status check cancelledSTATUSCHECK_USER_CANCELLED  subtask=-1 task=Deploy
DEBU[0018] marking resource status check cancelledSTATUSCHECK_USER_CANCELLED  subtask=-1 task=Deploy
DEBU[0018] marking resource status check cancelledSTATUSCHECK_USER_CANCELLED  subtask=-1 task=Deploy
DEBU[0018] marking resource status check cancelledSTATUSCHECK_USER_CANCELLED  subtask=-1 task=Deploy
DEBU[0018] marking resource status check cancelledSTATUSCHECK_USER_CANCELLED  subtask=-1 task=Deploy
DEBU[0018] marking resource status check cancelledSTATUSCHECK_USER_CANCELLED  subtask=-1 task=Deploy
DEBU[0018] pod statuses could not be fetched this time due to following errors occurred context canceled  subtask=-1 task=Deploy
DEBU[0018] marking resource status check cancelledSTATUSCHECK_USER_CANCELLED  subtask=-1 task=Deploy
DEBU[0018] pod statuses could not be fetched this time due to following errors occurred context canceled  subtask=-1 task=Deploy
DEBU[0018] marking resource status check cancelledSTATUSCHECK_USER_CANCELLED  subtask=-1 task=Deploy
DEBU[0018] setting skaffold deploy status to STATUSCHECK_IMAGE_PULL_ERR.  subtask=-1 task=Deploy
Cleaning up...
DEBU[0018] Running command: [kubectl --context kubernetes-admin@kubernetes delete --ignore-not-found=true --wait=false -f -]  subtask=-1 task=DevLoop
 - deployment.apps "auth-depl" deleted
 - service "auth-srv" deleted
 - deployment.apps "auth-mongo-depl" deleted
 - service "auth-mongo-srv" deleted
 - deployment.apps "client-depl" deleted
 - service "client-srv" deleted
 - deployment.apps "expiration-depl" deleted
 - deployment.apps "expiration-redis-depl" deleted
 - service "expiration-redis-srv" deleted
 - ingress.networking.k8s.io "ingress-service" deleted
 - deployment.apps "nats-depl" deleted
 - service "nats-srv" deleted
 - deployment.apps "orders-depl" deleted
 - service "orders-srv" deleted
 - deployment.apps "orders-mongo-depl" deleted
 - service "orders-mongo-srv" deleted
 - deployment.apps "payments-depl" deleted
 - service "payments-srv" deleted
 - deployment.apps "payments-mongo-depl" deleted
 - service "payments-mongo-srv" deleted
 - deployment.apps "tickets-depl" deleted
 - service "tickets-srv" deleted
 - deployment.apps "tickets-mongo-depl" deleted
 - service "tickets-mongo-srv" deleted
INFO[0054] Cleanup completed in 35.7 seconds             subtask=-1 task=DevLoop
DEBU[0054] Running command: [tput colors]                subtask=-1 task=DevLoop
DEBU[0054] Command output: [256
]                        subtask=-1 task=DevLoop
1/12 deployment(s) failed
```

This is the `expiration-depl.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: expiration-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: expiration
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: expiration
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: expiration
          image: learnertester/expiration
          env:
            - name: NATS_CLIENT_ID
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.name
            - name: NATS_URL
              value: 'http://nats-srv:4222'
            - name: NATS_CLUSTER_ID
              value: ticketing
            - name: REDIS_HOST
              value: expiration-redis-srv
```

And this is the `expiration-redis-depl.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: expiration-redis-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: expiration-redis
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: expiration-redis
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: expiration-redis
          image: redis
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: expiration-redis-srv
spec:
  selector:
    app: expiration-redis
  ports:
    - name: db
      protocol: TCP
      port: 6379
      targetPort: 6379
```

#### Information

- Skaffold version:  v2.0.3
- Operating system: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
- Installed via: Snap
- Contents of skaffold.yaml:

```yaml
apiVersion: skaffold/v2alpha3
kind: Config
deploy:
  kubectl: 
    manifests:
      - ./infra/k8s/*
build:
  local:
    push: false
  artifacts:
    - image: learnertester/auth
      context: auth
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      sync:
        manual:
          - src: 'src/**/*.ts'
            dest: .
    - image: learnertester/ticketing-client
      context: client
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      sync:
        manual:
          - src: '**/*.js'
            dest: .
    - image: learnertester/tickets
      context: tickets
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      sync:
        manual:
          - src: 'src/**/*.ts'
            dest: .
    - image: learnertester/orders
      context: orders
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      sync:
        manual:
          - src: 'src/**/*.ts'
            dest: .
    - image: learnertester/expiration
      context: expiration
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      sync:
        manual:
          - src: 'src/**/*.ts'
            dest: .
    - image: learnertester/payments
      context: payments
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      sync:
        manual:
          - src: 'src/**/*.ts'
            dest: .
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all what 'local Kubernetes' are you using?

In the deploy section in skaffold.yaml, you need to specify which k8s context you want to use for the deployments, like so:

```yaml
deploy:
  kubeContext: minikube
```

To check available k8s contexts on your machine type:

```
kubectl config get-contexts
```